# How to print more than one items in QListWidget if more than one items selected

Tags: python, pyqt, python-3.4, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have QListWidget and there are strings there, when I select a string, I wanted to display the index number and text of that. But the problem is, if I select more than 1 items, it doesn't display all of the indexes. It displays only one.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Pencere(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.listwidget = QListWidget(self)
        self.listwidget.addItems(["Python","Ruby","Go","Perl"])
        self.listwidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)


        self.buton = QPushButton(self)
        self.buton.setText("Ok")
        self.buton.clicked.connect(self.but)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buton)

    def but(self):
        print (self.listwidget.currentRow()+1)


uygulama = QApplication(sys.argv)
pencere = Pencere()
pencere.show()
uygulama.exec_()
```

How can I display all of the items names and indexes if I select more than 1 items?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this

```
def but(self):
    x = self.listwidget.selectedItems()
    for y in x:
        print (y.text())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use QListWidget's `selectedItems()` function, which returns a list. `currentRow()` only returns a single integer, and is intended to be used only in single-selection instances.

Once you've got the list of QListWidgetItems, you can use the `text()` function on each item to retreive the text.

Getting the index is slightly more complicated, you'll have to get a `QModelIndex` object from your original `QListWidgetItem` using the `QListWidget.indexFromItem()` and then use the `QModelIndex.row()` function.

---

Source: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems
<sub>*Note: You specified PyQt5 in your tags, but the API of QListWidget remains the same in this case; see the [C++ API docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems) if you want to make sure.*</sub>

Comment: But how can I print the indexes and strings of selected items with that method?

Comment: It prints `[<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem object at 0x02DEEDA0>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem object at 0x02DEEDF0>]` like this. For example how can I print `Python,Ruby`?

Comment: For the text, see the [API of QListWidgetItem](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidgetitem.html), particularly the [`text()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidgetitem.html#text) function, and for the index, use QListWidget's [`indexFromItem()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#indexFromItem) and its respective [`row()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmodelindex.html#row) function.

Comment: selectedItems().text() not working. If you put an example to your answer I think we solve the problem so far. Giving docs not working.

Comment: Its not `selectedItems().text()`! `text()` is a member function of `QListWidgetItem`. So you'd want to do something like `[itm.text() for itm in self.listwidget.selectedItems()]` to get it as a list of string/QString